# Are those two questions not duplicates?

Tags: discussion, imdb

I am always against those [IMDb questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/930/is-question-regarding-a-movie-website-on-topic), but the community decided to keep them. But now it's too much because we are even keeping duplicates, too. Look at those two questions:

[Are IMDB ratings objectively credible?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16037/are-imdb-ratings-objectively-credible)

[Are movie production companies hiring people to rate their movies on IMDB?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/are-movie-production-companies-hiring-people-to-rate-their-movies-on-imdb)

They might appear to be different but they both are covering the IMDb credibility. So, in my opinion one should be closed. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 3):

They are certainly related - they are about the credibility of IMDB's movie rating score, however they are not duplicates in my opinion..

One is about the general credibility of the score, e.g. is a movies rated 7.0 objectively better than a movie rated 6.0.

The second relates to a specific technique or even 'urban legend' of a technique that might be used by movie marketing types to boost the score of specific movies.  If this were true, and actually possible - it would clearly be a factor to undermine the credibility of the rating system.  However if its not true, or even if the overall averaging of the effect against thousands of other general users means the effect is small - then it still leaves the first more general question completely valid (if not that interesting).

Comment: Thanks for the response But I still think answer to one applicable to other too and they are duplicate to me. And why are we entertaining credibility question of an alien site. Soon we will going to handle complains about rotten tomatoes ,Wikipedia and metacritic.

Comment: @AnkitSharma *"And why are we entertaining credibility question of an alien site. Soon we will going to handle complains about rotten tomatoes ,Wikipedia and metacritic."* - While I agree with this opinion, that's an entirely different question (which sadly enough already seems to have been answered by the community, albeit in the IMHO (and IYHO, too) wrong way ;-)). But once on-topic, I agree with *iandotkelly* that they're not really exact duplicates, even if very related (and I would personally rather have one of those than two).

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I am sympathetic to your point of view here - but since ratings are of interest to movie viewers I don't see much harm in letting them go.  Personally I downvoted the older question as it seemed more about urban-legends than reality.  If we start to become support for IMDB then we can revisit the issue.