# How to improve 'How to find happy, upbeat material in rankings?'

Tags: support

Would someone please advise if [my question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/how-to-find-happy-upbeat-material-in-rankings) can be amended? I'd appreciate its reopening.

I've tried the asserted duplicate but it doesn't turn on the additional condition of works 'that are also praised and acclaimed' (and not just 'similar').

Moreover, I may not know of 'the one I like' that it presumes to exist.

Answer (score 3):

Though, the problem I see with this question isn't so much that it is a duplicate of an existing question (in fact the existing question was created in order to have a duplicate closing target for off-topic questions), but the fact that it is basically asking for resources and search techniques to find things. The fact that it's movies it's looking for doesn't make the question so much related to the topic of movies and TV at all. I thus can't see many ways to amend it in order to make it on-topic.

This problem is similar to the one adressed in this related meta post (which admittedly has not been completely decided by the community either yet):

[Are questions regarding a movie website On-Topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/930/49)

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't really isn't any way to word this question that it would be considered separate from the FAQ question unless it was made a [list question which are also frowned upon](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/list-of-movies-question-can-we-allow-it).

Though I can certainly see why you didn't feel satisfied with it, that question is a bit lacking in specifics on how to find the movies with those resources and I'll try and work out some more in-depth "how to use IMDb" answer for it later, but here's a preview which deals with your case:

You could try [Lists](http://www.imdb.com/lists/), they're user made, but [they have tags](http://www.imdb.com/lists/tag) and you can filter them. An example for your case would be [Lists tagged 'feel-good'](http://www.imdb.com/lists/tag/Feel-Good/) which has 19 lists, and once you go on an individual list you can sort it by IMDb rating (user rating), or [MOVIEmeter](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?prowhatisstarmeter) (some combination of user rating, IMDb searching and web hits):

[image: Image of IMDb filters]

Edit: My IMDB advanced usage answer can be found [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/24154/9682).

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively for your detail. I will upvote your other stellar answers on the main site and await further details.